# Dynamic front end to edit and save JSON blobs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, dynamic

I am building a configuration app that would save configuration objects as JSON blobs on mySql. Would like to have rails dynamically create appropriate input forms based on the JSON.

Is there a tool for that purpose, a gem for example or built-in rails feature?

Please point me to such tools, preferably ones with validations too. This is different than say RailsAdmin which is a front end for each table. I only have 1 table.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where you can just say "I think this problem has been solved before, please provide me the answer(s)". Do some researches on your own, we will gladly help you implement them.

Comment: I am not asking to solve a problem. I am asking if there are gems available or even better if there is a Rails built-in feature that does it.